# Using Google Maps APIv3, Javascript too heavy on client

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I am loading around 1000 markers, and it makes map zooming and panning very slow. If I use a KML Layer, will it speed up? And where does it stand with GeoRSS? Please explain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does run better, when I have thousands of markers, but map panning is not smooth, when using KML with few markers. This is what I noticed in Google Maps. Google Earth Browser Plugin, on the other hand, performs admirably when kml data is thrown at it. Overall, I will be using JS, till about 300 markers, and then seamlessly switch to KML.

Problems with using a KML file -> Local testing is difficult because I need to upload the KML to public domain every time. But in a real world scenario, it would perform well.